# Unable to echo images from full path

Tags: codeigniter, filepath

I’m trying to display all images from the path ‘uploads/profile’. While it partially works, it’s also including the “alt” place holder (see image) for those that are in the ‘uploads’ directory. In other words it’s displaying ALL images from the database table: Is there a way I can remove the place holders from the ‘uploads’ folder and just show the images that are physically in the ‘/profile’?

My View:

```
<?php foreach($main_model as $images): ?>  
<table class="GeneratedTable">  
<tr><td><img class="thumb" src="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/profile/".$images->imageName;?>" alt="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" ></td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: images are where to store its depend to folder directory if your directory folder are set to proper then echo images otherwise thumb

Comment: can you plz tell me what the parent directory uploads/profile/ so we are undersntading you

Comment: in which folder images have to stored?

Answer (score 0):

First, Check if the file exists or not in the directory with `file_exists()`. If yes then show it.

```
<?php foreach($main_model as $images): ?>  
    <table class="GeneratedTable"> 

      <?php $image = $images->imageName ? $images->imageName : '';
      $file_with_path = base_url('uploads/profile/'. $image);
      if(!empty($image) && file_exists($file_with_path )):?> 

      <tr><td><img class="thumb" src="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/profile/".$images->imageName;?>" alt="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" ></td></tr>
<?php endif; endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: I just saw your code. The logic seems clear but I'm getting a blank screen with it. I tried to use $image, $file_with_path in the echo instead of $images->imageName but still shows a blank screen.

Comment: That's an improvement and we may be close. Thanks.

Comment: by the way. I also think that the problem may lie with the "foreach statement" which is causing the code to display ALL the images from the db table with the ones in the 'uploads' folder to show a place holder instead of the actual image?

Comment: If this doesn't work, I'm trying another approach I think will work. but I need some help with the code. I have a function now that moves the image from 'uploads' to 'uploads/profile'. And in addition to imagePath in the db table, I added 'profilePath'. I'm trying to add a line of code that will not only copy the image from one path to the other but also move it from imagePath to profilePath in the db. This way I can just echo 'profile' where the pics will be in profilePath. Please let me know what you think. Thanks for helping.

Comment: foreach ($rows as $row) {
             UPDATE images SET profilePath = imagePath WHERE user_id = $user_id AND imagePath != ''         
             copy($source_file, $profilePic);